# How do I get vBulletin forum URL?

Tags: php, vbulletin

I am writing a SQL query to query a vBulletin database. My file resides in the forum's root directory. I will create a HTML file and add a link to title_clean field. How can I get the URL? There is no link field in the database.

```
SELECT  `title_clean` ,  `description_clean` ,  `replycount` ,  `threadcount` 
FROM  `forum` fr
```

Comment: vBulletin stores the settings in the database as a serialized array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I got the URL/link

```
$link = fetch_seo_url('thread|nosession|fullurl|js', $thread, array('goto' => 'newpost'));
```